# Postman returns ' Could not get any response '

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

Postman returns  ' Could not get any response '  when I send a Post request, but get a request to other URL works just fine. please how can I resolve this issue? index.js is the entry point to my application. the get URL below is working.

## index.js

```
    const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app= express()

//body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//config
dotenv.config()
//connect to db
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    { useNewUrlParser: true },
    ()=>{
        console.log('contented to db')
    }
)

//import route
const authRoute = require('./ROUTES/auth')

app.use('', authRoute)

app.use('/api/user', authRoute)

//start server
app.listen(5000);



# auth.js #
```

all routings are done in auth.js

```
        const express =require('express')
    const router = express.Router();
    const User = require('./moduls/User')
    
    
    router.get('/',(req, res)=>{
        res.send('home')
    })
    
    //validation schema
    const joi =require('@hapi/joi');
    const regSchema ={
        name:joi.string().min(6).required(),
        email:joi.string().required().email(),
        password:joi.string().min(8).required()
    }
    
    router.post('/register', async(req, res)=>{
        //check and return error status
        const { error } = joi.ValidationError(regSchema);
        if(error) return res.status(400).json({message: err})
        const emailExist = await User.findOne(req.body.email)
        if (emailExist) return res.status(400).json({message:'there is a user with this email'})
    
        //get user object
        const user =new User({
            name:req.body.name,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:req.body.password,
            rePassword:req.body.rePassword
        })
        try{
            await user.save()
            .then(data=>{
                res.json(data)
            })
        }
        catch(err){
            res.status(400).json({message: err})
        }
    
    })
    
    module.exports=router;
```

## modules/User.js

user module in the modules folder

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema =new  mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        min:6,
        max:30
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        max:100
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        min:8
    },
    rePassword:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        min:8
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The .save() function returns a promise that you can await. You don't need to use .then() when using async/await.

Instead of this.

```
await user.save()
.then(data=>{
    res.json(data)
})
```

I'd do this.

```
const data = await user.save();
res.json(data);
```